# iOS close popovercontroller from view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I was digging around on SO and thought I had figured out how to do this but my test failed. I'm trying to close a popovercontroller from the viewcontroller that is launched/contained (I'm still a bit fuzzy on the poc and vc relationship) by it.

In my viewcontroller .h I have this:

```
@interface OAI_vcOperatingRooms : UIViewController {

    OAI_ColorManager* colorManager;
    OAI_FileManager* fileManager;

    UIPopoverController* myPopOverController;

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIPopoverController* myPopOverController;

- (void) closeVC : (id) sender;
```

and in the .m file

```
UIButton* btnClose = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btnClose addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(closeVC:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btnClose setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnClose.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

    [self.view addSubview:btnClose];

- (void) closeVC : (id) sender {

    [myPopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

in the uiview that calls the popovercontroller, I've referenced the viewcontroller and added this:

```
//operating rooms
        controller2 = [[OAI_vcOperatingRooms alloc] initWithNibName:@"OAI_vcOperatingRooms" bundle:nil];
        popoverController2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller2];

        controller2.myPopOverController = popoverController2;
```

No errors but nothing happens when I hit the close button. Is it possible  to reference a POC from within the VC?

Thanks

Comment: Yes I have done it before. Are you sure your myPopOverController isn't nil in your - (void) closeVC function?

Comment: Yes, I have done this routinely, almost identical to your code. Something is not as you expect! Time for some NSLogs!

Comment: Who told you to use the weak property? I hope you're using ARC, you don't need that 2-step alloc-init, just directly do `controller2.myPopOverController = [[UIPop...`.

Comment: myPopOverController is null...grrr

Comment: got it to work...did change weak to strong but also changed in my close method: - (void) closeVC : (id) sender {
    [self.thePopUpController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}, made a few other changes as well to the code to clean it up, thanks for all the assists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ott’s comment is on to something - try using a `strong` property instead of a `weak` one. A `weak` property is likely to get set to nil by ARC immediately after its last use. A `strong` property will stick around for the lifetime of its parent object (in this case, your `UIViewController` subclass), unless you set it to `nil` early.

Note: you probably don’t need `UIPopoverController *myPopOverController;` in your interface, since Xcode will automatically generate `_myPopOverController` as a backing variable.